# Wordpress - Broken Menu in Media Master Theme

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, content-management-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wordpress Theme Navigational Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910866/wordpress-theme-navigational-menu)

I am using the theme Media Master, which can be seen at:

http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/media-master

The only problem is that the top navigational menu nodes which have subnodes break up.

Anyone with a solution to fix the broken sub-navigational system?

Thanks :)

Comment: The entire theme looks broken up. I'd find a new theme man, this one hasn't been updated in over 2 years and looks way out of date.

Answer (score 0):

The theme has not been updated in over 2 years :O So I personally suggest you not to use it since Wordpress has changed a lot since then..